# Configuring a Canon MG5420 in Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, software-installation, canon

My new printer (1 month old) can not be recognized  Canon Pixma MG5420.

The Canon site said clearly that it does not work with Linux, but I know there are so many experts here that perhaps know some trick to make it works. I'm very very new in this platform, I'd appreciate step by step instructions if it is possible.

Comment: Hope this helps:
If you have a cloud enabled printer like the Pixma series from Canon, you don't have to go through this and can securely print from your Ubuntu in a clean fashion.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to help you. On the European site of Canon, you can find the drivers for MG5400 series printers. The drivers you need are the two Debian Packagearchives (Ubuntu is based on Debian), one for the scanner, and the other for the printer.

Here is the link where you can get your driver.

http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG5440.aspx

Comment: Not sure the 5440 drivers would work with the 5420.

Comment: This driver is for the MG5400 series. The MG5440 and the MG5450 leads to the same driver.

Comment: yeah, but op use 54 **20**

Comment: It doesn't matter. It is for the whole MG54xx series. This is not the first time I face this kind of issue with Canon, and this is what I always did to make them work.

Answer (score 1):

I went a slightly different direction - as of 2017, the UK driver is looking for deprecated dependencies - libtiff4, which depends in turn on libjpeg8.

Those are available [here](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libjpeg8) for libjpeg8 under wheezy, and [here](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libtiff4) for libtiff4 under wheezy as well.

Once you have the UK driver, and these two packages into one directory, your commands will look something like:

```
sudo dpkg -i libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libtiff4_3.9.6-11_amd64.deb
cd cnijfilter-mg5400series-3.80-1-deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

The install script will then run properly and you should be able to answer the questions without any trouble.  The network detection might take a second or two.

Solution works for:  Linux Mint Debian Edition (Betsy), but should also apply to Ubuntu and other Debian distros based on the 3.16.0-4 kernel (wheezy).

Answer (score 0):

If Canon themself says it doesn't work, I doubt anyone would step in to make some reverse engineering and make it work (a la nouveau driver for Nvidia video cards). Normally, the makers should release the documentation of their products so the community could create some modules. If this have not been done with your printer you are pretty much out of luck.

Comment: Canon is a little bit special. At the same time as they say to their American and Canadian customers that their products cannot work with Linux, they provide the Linux drivers for their European customers.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the canon usa site and as predicted there is no linux driver there.  however the european site did have the drivers as a deb package to download.  I downloaded the 2 debian driver files that were gzipped tar files.  i untarred them in the download directory and then used gdebi to install them... the 32 bit and 64 bit are both in the .deb file so you have to click on the "packages" sub directory to see the 64 bit and 32 bit packages inside.  then i find that there is a "common" and a "model specific" driver in each of the 2 packages i downloaded (1 for scanner and 1 for printing) so i installed 4 pakages total (64 bit common for scanning, 64 bit model specific for scanning, 64 bit common for printing, and 64 bit model specific for printing.  then i used the normal everyday "add printer" in linux and voila it woiks.  I did this on linux mint 16  it works the same for linux mint 17.